# Dart source code not loading in flutter web integration tests

Tags: flutter, flutter-integration-test

I am running few integration tests on flutter web using following command,

```
flutter driver --target=integration_test/main_test.dart --flavor rc  --driver=test_driver/web_driver.dart --browser-name  chrome --debug -d chrome  --dart-define=ENV=rc  --web-port 5000
```

but not able to debug as the all source code in chrome dev-tools are having 'index.html' content rather then original dart file content. The Source code is not loading correctly on `flutter drive`.

Source code appears if I run normal flutter web using `flutter run -d chrome` but not in integration tests.